# How to remove duplicate entries in dash?

Tags: 14.04, unity-dash, .desktop

After upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 from 12.04 I have duplicate entries in dash.

[image]

How can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In Dash, applications are represented by `.desktop` files. These files are located in either `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`. For snap programs, also look at `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications`

What you see in Dash is not the *filename* of these `.desktop` files, but the (application-) name that is defined in the `Name=` line, inside the file.

When you have duplicate appearances of the same application in Dash, it almost certainly means that you have desktop files in either `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share applications` (or even the snap folder) with a different *file* name, but representing the same application, and with the same `Name=` line.

This is for example the result when I copy the gedit.desktop file, rename it to `monkey.desktop` and copy it into `/usr/share/applications`:

[image]

In your case it is probably the result of installed *new versions* of applications you already had installed, these new versions install new `.desktop` files, but with a slightly different (file-)name.

What you should do is look inside both directories, find these "almost duplicate" `.desktop` files, remove the oldest and keep the latest.

**Some more information**

From the two locations: `/usr/share/applications` and `~/.local/share/applications`, the latter takes precedence. If two `.desktop` files with the same filename exist in both directories, the local one shows up in Dash (if just copied, it takes a logout / login). That is why it is normally good practice to first copy a `.desktop` file to the local directory (to add items to the launcher's quicklist for example) before editing, and leave the global one untouched.

If you install a newer version of some software, and the newly installed `.desktop` file name differs from the old one (and the old one is *not* removed for some reason), the application will have multiple occurrences in Dash. The same happens when the `.desktop` file *is* replaced, but people forget they have a local (edited) version of the `.desktop` file.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't have any .desktop files in ~/.local/share applications just similar files in /usr/share/applications.

Comment: That is very well possible! I will add some information to my answer.

Comment: For snap programs, check `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications`