# Wrong display name and icon in launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

I am trying to correct the icon and the display name of Arduino IDE in my launcher. I used to lock on the sketch of Arduino IDE 1.6.3 in 7 April into the launcher. It didn't work as I expected so I removed it and I reinstalled the old version of Arduino IDE with this command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install arduino arduino-core
```

The problem here is whenever I opened the Arduino IDE, it still showed me the name of sketch and Arduino 1.6.3 instead of just Arduino IDE.

How to remove the old one and correct the display icon here!

[image]
[image: Search menu]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either in `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`, a "left over" `.desktop` file must be left behind.

Remove the duplicate `desktop` file(s), log out and back in and it should be fixed. If you are having doubts on which is the right one to remove: `.desktop` files show their icon once you make them executable. You can also look inside the file (drag it over an opened gedit window).

*File-* names of the .desktop files can be confusing, since the name you see in Dash can (and will) be different from the name in Dash; in Dash, you see the name, defined in the Name= line of the file.

Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/516346/72216

Comment: I checked in `~/.local/share/applications` and `/usr/share/applications` but I saw only one entry for Arduino as I mentioned above, in `local`, there is nothing similar with the one that I want to remove

Comment: @ThoVo You mean in `~/.local/share/applications`? You can remove that one, since you must have one in `/usr/share/applications`, looking at the way you installed it (globally). Names of the `.desktop` files can be confusing, since the name you see in Dash can be different (in Dash, you see the name, defined in the `Name=` line of the file). Remove the local one and log out/in, then try again :)

Comment: I found the correct one, it just had the different name, but when I opened it, it was the problem. Thank a lot!

Comment: @ThoVo Perfect! glad it works :)

Comment: try `grep -r 'your launcher name'` and it will show the entry file. so you can delete it.

Comment: Also, I executed `update-desktop-database command` from https://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/how-to-install-and-edit-desktop-files-on-linux-desktop-entries/ and it didn't require to logout and login. just the icon existed but it was not working when clicked, thus it worked.