# Can ~/.local/share/applications override /usr/share/applications?

Tags: .desktop

I need to launch some applications on KDE with some added config changes. The best way to do that without messing up with `/` is by copying `.desktop` file of individual applications, that I need to change config of, from `/usr/share/applications`, add options, and then copy them to `~/.local/share/applications`.

I was wondering if that is going to cause any problems that I am not aware of. And if there is a better way to do that say by not copying everything but only adding a changes in the desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications`.

Thanks.

Comment: Nono! only the specific ones!!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes it should work to copy the ones you want to modify to `~/.local/share/applications`, and shouldn't cause too many problems unless you make some bad edits (e.g. removing mime-types etc). Copying all the ones mean that if they are updated at `/usr/share/applications`, they won;t be updated in `~/.local/share/applications`, and the launchers for apps you remove will remain. Don't bother copying all of them that is unnecessary.

After you make the edits, running `update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications/` should make sure the new launcher is recognised, so is shown in the Dash/Menu.

Unity's launcher, and probably Gnome's Dash will likely still show the version in `/usr/share/applications`, so you will need to unlock and lock the icon. Gnome 3 may also need a restart, Nautilus may do as well so logging out and logging back in should fix this.

Reading the following may help with making edits:

- http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries

Comment: I wonder in what case would I see dulicate entry for an app that have a desktop file in both `/usr/share/applications` and `~/.local/share/applications`.

Comment: @donniezazen see: http://askubuntu.com/a/516346/72216

Comment: @JacobVlijm I see if the filenames are same then the one in `~/.local/share/applications` takes precedence. Thanks.

Comment: @donniezazen something to keep in mind with locally edited `.desktop` files is that they are not updated if an application is updated (including the global `.desktop` file), but not the local one. Chrome is famous for that, resulting in duplicate icons.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.10, if I copy the Terminal entry `org.gnome.Terminal.desktop`, then when it opens the modified `.desktop` from super + search as desired, but the icon shown on the dock for this new modified terminal window still refers to the system `.desktop`.

Comment: Still works great in Debian 11, nearly 8 years later.

Comment: Oh, and if you make edits, and those shortcuts were in your list of "Favorites", the entry in the Favorites will still need to be updated, too.

Answer (score 3):

#### Don't copy all files/directories from  `/usr/share/applications`

It is indeed good practice to copy a `.desktop` file locally before editing it. That is the appropriate procedure.  After you copied/edited it and logged out/in, the local one will overrule the global one.

Not all files in `/usr/share/applications` are meant to be run by the user directly however. Some files possibly are no `.desktop` files at all and even a few directories may exist. That is (a.o.) why you should not simply copy *everything* from `/usr/share/applications` into `~/.local/share/applications`.

There is also no reason at all to copy all `.desktop` files locally. The local ones will only overrule the global ones *if* the local one exists. If the local one does not exist, the global one still is "in charge".

#### Is there a risk if I copy the complete contents of `/usr/share/applications` to `~/.local/share/applications`?

Apart from creating useless duplicates, copying *everything* from `/usr/share/applications` can cause conflicts starting up your desktop. I actually did that once as an experiment (`Unity`), had to fix things with a startup usb.

#### Conclusion:

Only copy global `.desktop` files to `~/.local/share/applications` if you have a reason to do that, and only copy (and edit) files specifically.

If you mess up a `.desktop` file somehow, the application won't startup from Dash or you are experiencing duplicate icons in Dash, if you do not manage to fix, simply remove the local `.desktop`, log out/in and things are as they were before.

Comment: Thanks for the write up. Just to let you know I should have been clearer I have no intention of copying the whole directory. I only meant to copy individual files.

Comment: @donniezazen Ah, then it should be fine. In most cases, if you *really* mess up a `.desktop` file, simply remove it log, out/in and things are as they were before.

Comment: Also do not hesitate to remove all .desktop from `~/.local/share/applications`  if you start to see strange behavior with your applications, browser starting strangely, multiples icons of the same app in the launcher, etc.

Comment: For Ubuntu 20.04, `'desktop` files in `~/.local/share/applications` with the same name did not override files sourced from `/usr/share/applications/`, even after `update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications/`. `XDG_DATA_HOME` when unset should default/apply `~/.local/share/applications` to supercede  `XDG_DATA_DIRS` dir locations like `/usr/share/applications/`. But I observed the opposite. E.g. `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop` was favored and my `~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop` customization failed to apply.