# How to make lubuntu (LXDE) terminal support Arabic or Persian language?

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, lxde

In my lubuntu machine terminal the Arabic letters are being displayed from left-to-right and they are not bound together (Altogether on a text editor everything is working correctly).

The reason for wanting terminal to display Arabic is that I'm trying to develop a Python program which uses graphical elements like TextBox (actually Entry in tkinter). I found different modules to output strings consisting of Arabic letters in a correct form but while the user is typing in the Textbox it displays the same way as in my terminal (from left to right and with isolated individual letters).

How can I get these scripts to display correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install *bicon* for this purpose.

So you can use this method for enable Persian or Arabic in *lxterminal*:

First, install `libfribidi0` and `libfribidi-dev` packages.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libfribidi0 libfribidi-dev
```

Then download and install `bicon`:

For **64bit** machines:

Download [this](https://launchpad.net/~behnam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/574787/+files/bicon_0.2.0-1ubuntu0~ppa4_amd64.deb) package and then install with this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i bicon_0.2.0-1ubuntu0~ppa4_amd64.deb
```

For **32bit** mchines:

Download [this](https://launchpad.net/%7Ebehnam/+archive/ppa/+build/574785/+files/bicon_0.2.0-1ubuntu0%7Eppa4_i386.deb) package and then install with this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i bicon_0.2.0-1ubuntu0~ppa4_i386.deb
```

Then for type Persian or Arabic in *lxterminal* you should run this command:

```
bicon.bin
```

---

But for automate this process you can edit `/usr/share/applications/lxterminal.desktop` file with this command:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/lxterminal.desktop
```

And apply this changes to that file:

1. Change `Exec=lxterminal` to `Exec=lxterminal -e bicon.bin`
2. Add `Terminal=true` to this file.

So after save the changes , you can see these lines in that file:

```
Exec=lxterminal -e bicon.bin
Terminal=true
```

So After changes, you can tap on *lxterminal* icon and type Persian (or Arabic).

---

But if you want to run *bicon* , also with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> buttons, you should do this steps:

Edit `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` file with this command:

```
nano ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml
```

Then change `lxsession-default terminal` command in `<!-- Launch a terminal on Ctrl + Alt + T-->` section to `lxterminal -e bicon.bin`.

So you should change:

```
  <!-- Launch a terminal on Ctrl + Alt + T-->
  <keybind key="C-A-T">
    <action name="Execute">
      <command>lxsession-default terminal</command>
    </action>
  </keybind>
```

To:

```
  <!-- Launch a terminal on Ctrl + Alt + T-->
  <keybind key="C-A-T">
    <action name="Execute">
<command>lxterminal -e bicon.bin</command>
    </action>
  </keybind>
```

Then run this command to apply this changes:

```
openbox --reconfigure
```

Comment: It's better to overwrite `/usr/share/applications/lxterminal.desktop` by creating `lxterminal.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications` instead of implementing you changes straight to the original file. also it's a good idea to leave some references ;)

Comment: @Ravexina Thanks for your reply and your help ; I've update my answer as you said.

Comment: @Ravexina I'm so sorry ; but when I test your solution in the VM it's not be worked. so I undo the changes

Comment: [Can ~/.local/share/applications override /usr/share/applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/610474/can-local-share-applications-override-usr-share-applications)

Comment: @ali76 I truly stand at awe of your professional expertise as well as highly organized and legible instruction you made to guide a layman as I am. Now lxterminal displays Persian seemlessly. Thank you. But the funny thing for me is that still Python IDLE and tkinter widgets are not doing so :(