# Why does my custom launcher open under a separate icon?

Tags: launcher, icons

I've created a custom launcher file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=P4V
Comment=Perforce Visual Client
Icon=/usr/lib/p4v/P4VResources/icons/P4-V_128x128.png
Exec=/usr/bin/p4v
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;
```

And dragged this file to my launcher. However, when I click the icon, it opens the application under a 2nd, different icon (I click the top one, it opens the application under the bottom one):

[image: launcher icons]

The bottom icon isn't present until after I launch the application using the top P4v icon that I manually added.

Comment: Is this a java app?

Comment: /usr/bin/pv4 is a script that apparently opens your app  in some manner that is  itself associated with an icon. Probably javascript - http://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce-visual-client

Comment: @doug nope, it is an application with a window and a "normal" `.desktop` file (including a set icon) in `/usr/share/applications` (I installed it to find out).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### If an application produces a second icon, *not* being a generic one

If an application generates a *second* icon in the Unity launcher *other* than a a grey, generic icon, there must be already an (other)  existing launcher, calling `p4v` in its main command:

An application's `.desktop` file by definition has a "main" command in the first line, starting with `Exec=`. This is the command that is run when the icon is clicked in the (`Unity`) launcher. Apart from that, a `.desktop` file *can* have one or more shortcut- sections, available when you right-click on the representing icon in the `Unity` launcher.

#### Multiple .desktop files calling the same application in their main command

The symptoms you are experiencing can happen when more than one `.desktop` file in either `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications` have the same ("main-") command in their *first* `Exec=` line, but the files are differently named.

P4v by default should install (and probably has installed) a `.desktop` file, named `p4vasp.desktop` in `/usr/share/applications`.

*How to fix*
Your problem should be fixed if you remove your own (probably local) `.desktop` file, then run `p4v` from Dash and pin it to the launcher.

#### What if you want to customize the existing launcher?

If you want to change the `.desktop` file's behaviour or e.g. its icon:

- copy the file from `/usr/share/applications` to `~/.local/share/applications`
- *don't* change the file's name
- open the file in `gedit` (drag it over an opened `gedit` window) and make the changes you'd like
- log out and back in, the local version of the `.desktop` file will overrule the global one.

To revert, simply remove the local one, log out and back in.

Related to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516207/how-to-remove-duplicate-entries-in-dash/516346#516346)

Comment: This answer is just as good in Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME 3

Comment: This answer is incorrect, as one can still end up with two icons in the Unity dock even if there are no duplicate .desktop files, as the other answer points out. It was the case for me.

Answer (score 19):

Solution that worked for me on ubuntu **18.04** when struggling with getting an AppImage added to my favorites. This solution is summarised from
https://beamtic.com/duplicated-icons-in-launcher

1. Launch application with duplicate icon
2. Get window class of application by executing

   ```
    xprop WM_CLASS
   ```
3. Click on main window of application. You should then receive output of the form

   ```
    WM_CLASS(STRING) = "some-thing", "different-thing"
   ```

Both `some-thing` and `different-thing` should work.

4. Find `<application-name>.desktop` file (likely in `~/.local/share/applications`)
5. Add the following line to desktop file and replace `Name_of_Window_Class` with either `some-thing` or `different-thing`:

   ```
    StartupWMClass=Name_of_Window_Class
   ```
6. Start/Restart the application

Comment: Worked, needed to solve this for robo3t 1.4 so for others the line is
`StartupWMClass=robo3t`

Comment: For my desktop file which has exec line `python3 my_script.py`, this does not work. I get `my_script.py` and `My_script.py`, both do not work.

Comment: Worked as well with Studio 3T 2023.2.0. Final line in *~/.local/share/applications/.desktop* file: `StartupWMClass=Studio 3T`